# vba open txt files, error message: document may be read-only or encrypted

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing vba code to remote control a device on the network. Basically the device would output a txt file, and I need my code to post-process it. The idea is not to have to manually open txt file in excel with deliminator. Here comes the problem.

The code segment for open the file is as follow:

```
Workbooks.OpenText fileName:= _
    path, _
    origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

The code stops here, with a message box saying "Excel cannot access 'filename'. The document may be read-only or encrypted."

A few elimination I have done:

1. path is correct. I printed it out in a cell and it is completely legitimate.
2. I can open the file normally. The file is not damaged or so.
3. The folder IS read-only. But when I tried open other txt files in other read-only folders, it works.

The only thing I could think of right now is the path is network-based (something like "\192.168.202.1\user (d)\User Files\filename.txt"). Btw network works fine. I tried type in the path in windows explorer and nothing goes wrong.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, for trouble shooting purposes, what happens if you run the following as a .vbs       `set fso = createobject("SCripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.OPenTextFile("_FileTargetPathHere_")
msgbox file.readall`

Comment: FYI, To run as .vbs, open any text editor, copy and paste and split into 3 lines of code (substitute in actual target path), save as .vbs, double click

Comment: Does it work if you map a drive instead of using the UNC path? so it would be "P:\user (d)\User Files\filename.txt"

Comment: I am not sure if we should consider the error message as really coming from failure to open the file. It might be coming from some bad parameters of the method. By the way, what is the purpose of the parameter `FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)`?

Comment: does `Open [Path] As.... ` work?

Comment: @DirkReichel I didn't try but I would assume it would work. The problem is simply open the file won't allow me to use deliminator.  It's a txt file that I need to open

Comment: @MatthewD I tried that. Same error message...

Comment: at least, there is another problem... do you need to log in somewhere? do you have an username / password? (just to be save: dont tell anyone your passwords) :D

Comment: `Open ... for ... as ...` works in a different way. its just a way to get more informations... i'd give you all code you need to insert it in a proper way into your sheet as long as it is the only way to get your data...

Comment: Ah, this is from something like a "SharePoint server"?

Comment: @P57 Thanks for the code for sanity check. I did as you suggested and the txt file is successfully read. How do I go from here?

Comment: @Davesexcel Sorry I'm not familiar with server terminologies... I don't know what is a sharepoint server, but for case it's just another PC connected to the same local network

Comment: @DirkReichel The PC where the folder lies doesn't require login credentials... The txt file is like this: each row has two numbers, separated by comma. What I want is to put them in two columns in a excelsheet...

Comment: @DirkReichel Is there a way around to import the data, as in open the txt file as txt, and somehow import the data?

Comment: I think the next thing I would do is try implementing the FileSystemObject approach in VBA. I posted an answer for this since it's too much code to post as a comment.  If that works, you can use it as is or continue troubleshooting as to why your original code does not.  IMHO, the FileSystemObject is better suited for this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

If the VBScript I posted works, I don't see any reason why the following code wouldn't work in VBA (I wrote this to process a text file to range as you described in your comment).

If you would, give it a try and let me know how it goes. Substitute your actual text file directory in for "C:\test.txt"

```
 Sub Test()
    Dim File As TextStream
    Set fso = CreateObject("SCripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = fso.OPenTextFile("C:\test.txt")

    'Example Reading Values to Collection Object
    Dim Text As Collection
    Set Text = New Collection

    'Skip first 2 lines
    For i = 1 To 2
        File.SkipLine
    Next

    'Find first line that meets a condition
    'This example uses the condition that
    'the the current line of text starts with a number
    Do
        TempString = File.ReadLine
    Loop Until IsNumeric(Left(TempString, 1))

    'Current structure includes initial line from condition to be read
    Text.Add Split(TempString, ",")

    'Continue reading to end of file
    Do Until File.AtEndOfStream
        'Added protection against empty lines producing subscript
        'out of range error if array expected
        TempString = File.ReadLine
        If TempString <> "" Then
            Text.Add Split(TempString, ",")
        End If
    Loop

    'Example Converting Collection to Array
    Dim A1() As Variant 'First Column of Data
    Dim A2() As Variant 'Second Column of Data

    ReDim A1(Text.Count, 1 To 2)
    ReDim A2(Text.Count, 1 To 2)

    For i = 1 To Text.Count
        A1(i, 1) = Text(i)(0)
        A2(i, 1) = Text(i)(1)
    Next

    'Example Writing Array to Range
    Range("A1:A" & Text.Count) = A1
    Range("C1:C" & Text.Count) = A2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. My txt file has a few header log lines (like time, device, etc) before actual data points. Does it affect splitting txt file by comma? Another thing is I want to write the data into two separate column, not adjacent column. How would I modify the last line of code before End Sub? (sorry I'm not familiar with vba array at all...)

Comment: @Victor The exact result would depend on if there are commas or not in the header section, but either way it shouldn't cause an error, although if it contained more than one comma then not all content would be copied to the workbook. Also, the old code I posted would throw an error if it processed an empty line.  I made adjustments to demonstrate how to do what you're asking.  Note that you can edit as needed because there is some redundancy.